# Firebase Rules string replace

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to create a function within my rule sets that will check that a particular document's field is null. Unfortunately one of the variables I pass in has a leading slash. For example: `/mycollection/xyz123`

```
rules_version = '1';

function hasNullStartDate(teamGuid, path) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/team/$(teamGuid)/$(path)).data.startDate == null
}

match /teams/{teamid}/{subpath=**} {
   allow delete: if hasNullStartDate(teamid, subpath)
}
```

I have tried removing the slash between my two variables `$(teamGuid)$(path)` but that causes a syntax error in the rules.

I have tried to do `.replace()` on the path, but that has ended up in a run time error. Maybe I didn't format it right or maybe it has to do with the rules version.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#replace

How can I get rid of that leading slash `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you don't want to use replace at all in this specific case, since a [Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) object (what you're passing to `get()`) isn't actually a string.  I think you'll be better off with a [string split](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#split) to get "mycollection" and "xyz123" into separate elements so you can build the path using their values individually.

Either that, or you can build the entire string the way you would expect for a normal string, and pass that string to `path()` to then pass to `get()`.  Again, see the [Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) documentation for more on that.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that was my fundamental problem. Even though I named my variable `path`, I didn't really realize it was a Path type. It is a little tricky because the Rules Playground interface makes it look like a string in the detailed information panel. In case anyone is curious, this is how I changed my return statement:
`return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(teamGuid)/$(path[0])/$(path[1])).data.startDate == null`